# Dynamic material progress bars Angular 9/10

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to create multiple progress bars in my project, the number of progress bars depends on the length of an array in the component.ts file, therefore the number of progress bars displayed is variable.

I need to approach this in two parts:

1. How do I display a dynamic number of material bars?  Would I ngFor loop be suitable while considering my next point
2. How could I programmatically change the value of each progress bar individually, perhaps based on ID or similar?

Any help with the above would be appreciated, including any short code samples to get me mving in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display progress bars by looping through an array which will save the progress values of the progress bars.

When you want to add a progress bar, just push a new item to this array.

Html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let bar of progressBars">
  <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="bar.progress"></mat-progress-bar>
</div>
```

TS:

```js
interface IProgressBar {
  progress: number;
}
...

progressBars: IProgressBar[] = [{ progress: 0 }];

addProgressBar() {
   this.progressBars.push({ progress: 0 });
}

updateProgressBar(progressBar: IProgressBar, value: number) {
   progressBar.progress = value;
}
```

**Demo:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-material-starter-sloszp

Answer (score 1):

for achieving multiple progress bar that too dynamically using the array that would be used for ***ngFor** is the correct approach.

You have to use the objects in the array.
Based on the progress you can update one of the fields of that object, and can bind the progress bar with that of field.

So for example, you can use the following line of codes for reference.

```
    <ng-template ngFor let-file [ngForOf]='files'>
  
    <mat-progress-bar [mode]="'determinate'" [color]="'primary'" [value]='file?.downloadState?.progress' flex="100"
      style='height:5px !important'></mat-progress-bar>
    </ng-template>
```